# How to push array into the existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Every time when i submit i what to add array into the array

```
Book.prototype.addItemToLocalSorage = function() {

    const row = []

    const item = this.findItemInLocalStorage()
    console.log('item', item)

    item.push(this.title)
    item.push(this.author)
    item.push(this.stars)

    row[row.length] = item

    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(row))

}
```

output:

```
[
  [
    ["ivo", "na drini cuprija", "1"],
    "ivo",
    "na drini cuprija",
    "2"
  ]
]
```

i what output to be:

```
[
  ["ivo", "na drini cuprija", "1"],
  ["ivo", "na drini cuprija", "2"]
]
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where `item` is declared as an empty array, that might be part of it. Also, I'm not sure you can use that bracket notation to update the value of an item in an array (someone correct me if I'm wrong). Wouldn't it be easier to just use `row.push(item)`?

Comment: `row[row.length] = x` is unconventional but should work

Comment: ^ no because that will do nothing. you mean `row.push(item)` I assume.

Comment: yes but its same result row[row.length] = x and row.push(item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be putting the fields into `row`, then pushing `row` onto `item`, not the other way around.

```
Book.prototype.addItemToLocalSorage = function() {
    const item = this.findItemInLocalStorage()
    console.log('item', item)
    const row = [this.title, this.author, this.stars]
    item.push(row)
    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(item))
}
```